# wxPython Equivalent to Tkinter .after()

Tags: python, wxpython, tkinter

Is there an equivalent to Tkinter's **.after()** in wxPython?

For those that don't know **.after()** allows the running of functions at some point in the future. This can be used to make loops with functions.

I'm attempting to make a clock, so this would be handy for making it tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you can use [wx.CallAfter](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter) and [wx.CallLater](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html). The former is roughly equivalent to tkinter's `after_idle` command, and the latter is the same as `after` (ie: it takes a number of milliseconds to wait as an argument)

As a third option you can use [wx.Timer](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Timer-class.html), upon which [wx.CallLater](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html) is based. This gives you more control over the scheduled jobs, allowing you to cancel or restart them (similar to what you can do with tkinter's `after_cancel`)

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions in wx.Python to do that.
You should check the "Process and events" section of the wxPython demos, More especifically those related with wx.Timer

> The wx.Timer class allows you to
>   execute code at specified intervals
>   from within the wxPython event loop.
>   Timers can be one-shot or repeating. 
>   This demo shows the principle method
>   of using a timer (with events) as well
>   as the convenient wx.FutureCall class.